I'm getting an error when creating a Kotlin project in Android Studio
I am new to learning Android Studio. I installed the IDE and every time I create a new project, I get an error. I tried changing the Gradle version, but it didn't work. I searched in several places and couldn't find a way to solve it. I want to fix it so I can learn, but I feel stuck and don't have acquaintances who program Android to help me. Here are the errors that appear:
Plugin [id: 'com.android.application', version: '8.4.1', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources:```


Second error:


Unsupported Java.
Your build is currently configured to use Java 22.0.1 and Gradle 8.6.```
In build.gradle.kts I have the following which was set by default once the app was created:
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.android.application) apply false
    alias(libs.plugins.jetbrains.kotlin.android) apply false
}

enter image description here you for helping me with my first question.
I searched for the error on Google, Stack Overflow in Spanish, and ChatGPT, but I couldn't find an answer. I hope you can help me resolve this error.

Are you sure you didn't switch the preselected language from "Kotlin" to "Java"? Please [edit] your question to also post the content of your module-level gradle file (as text, not as screenshot).

what java version do you have on your machine? and current android studio version?
